# How to set a NSDate for a notification every two hours?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I need to make a `NSDate` to set a local notification so it fires every 2 hours or well at every specific time.

I don't know how to do this though, so it will be greatly appreciated if someone can show me how...

I saw something like this but I don't know how it works:

```
notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 60];
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/repeatInterval

Comment: But note that you're basically constrained to repeat every hour and ignore half of them, if you want every two hours.  If you want an event every two hours *while the app is running* you can use an NSTimer with a repeat interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

60*60 is 3600 seconds from now, so logically:

```
notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 120];
```

Which will fire every two hours, for more information on `dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow` see the [NSDate Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow%3a)

Comment: This will not fire **every** two hours, but just once after two hours.

Comment: iMartin is correct, it seems I overlooked the question slightly, to do this I would look at the UILocalNotification's repeatInterval property